# How can I write code that works differently for different operating systems?

Tags: c#, operating-system, platform

I am Writing a File I/O code

I found out that each OS use different newline characters

so I wanna make a code that works differently for each OS
like below code

```
if(isWindows)
{
    Console.Write("Hello World\r\n");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Hello World\n");
}
```

Please let me know if you know a good way!

Comment: Did you try [`System.Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-8.0)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `Console.WriteLine()` instead?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-8.0 - if you don't like the character `Console.WriteLine` produces consider the remark `You can change the line terminator by setting the TextWriter.NewLine property of the Out property to another string.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to check for line breaks, you can use [System.Environment.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-8.0). This will return \r\n for non-Unix platforms and \n for Unix platforms.

```
Console.Write("Hello World" + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

However, if you need to implement separate code logic for each operating system, you could use [RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?view=net-9.0). This method can identify the following platforms:

- FreeBSD
- Linux
- OSX
- Windows

Your code would look something like this:

```
if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    Console.Write("Hello World\r\n");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Hello World\n");
}
```